# how to write Arabic through keypad in titanium android?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, font-family

I am using Titanium sdk version 2.1.1 and android sdk 2.2, I am trying to write some thing in arabic in text area. I tried it by adding fonts and other many ways but do not show the arabic in phone.Please help if you have any solution to that.
Ali

Comment: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) is about programming questions.

Comment: My question is programming related not architecture related!

Answer (score 0):

Go through this titanium community link. Read all comments you will get some idea

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/124533/utf-8--unreadable-characters-in-tableview